# Real Analysis, Problem 3.2.14 The Radon Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Problem 3.3.14 - If $\nu$ is an arbitrary signed measure and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X,M)$ such that $\nu\ll \mu$, there exists an extended $\mu$-integrable function $f:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ such that $d\nu = fd\mu$. Hints:
>
> a.) It suffices to assume that $\mu$ is finite and $\nu$ is positive.
>
> b.) With these assumptions, there exists an $E\in M$ that is $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$ such that $\mu(E)\geq \mu(F)$ for all sets $F$ that are $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$.
>
> c.) The Radon-Nikodym theorem applies on $E$. If $F\cap E = \emptyset$, then either $\nu(F) = \mu(F) = 0$ or $\mu(F) > 0$ and $|\nu(F)| = \infty$.

Attempted proof - Consider $\mu(E)$ where $E$ is a $\sigma$-finite set for $\nu$. Since we have that $\mu$ is finite then clearly $\mu(E)$ must be bounded which implies it has a supremum. We will define the supremum as $$L = \sup\{F: F \ \text{is} \  \sigma-\text{finite for} \ \nu\}$$
Now lets take a sequence $\{E_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ that are $\sigma$-finite with respect to $\nu$ and $\mu(E_n)\rightarrow L$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Now let $$E = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_n$$ then $\mu(E) \leq L$ since it is taken to be a countable union of $\sigma$-finite sets. On the other hand, $\mu(E)\geq \mu(E_n)$ for all $n$ and since $\mu(E_n)\rightarrow L$ then $\mu(E) = L$. Now since $\mu(E) = L$ then clearly by definition of $L$ we have that $\mu(E) > \mu(F)$ for all sets $F$ that are $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$. Now we apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem: so, suppose that $F\cap E = \emptyset$ well since $\nu\ll\mu$ then by definition $\nu(F) = \mu(F) = 0$. If $\mu(F) > 0$ then for sake of contradiction suppose $|\nu(F)|\neq \infty$. Then since $\mu$ is finite $\mu(F\cup E) > \mu(E)$ then this implies that $E\cup F$ is not $\sigma$-finite since a $\sigma$-finite set with a union of a finite set is $\sigma$-finite. Therefore $|\nu(F)| = \infty$.

Thus I believe we can refer to Radon-Nikidym theorem to conclude that there exists an extended $\mu$-integrable function $f:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ such that $d\nu = fd\mu$.

I am not sure if this is completely correct, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're still not able to decide on your own whether your analysis proofs are correct, even after asking literally **dozens** of these proof-verification questions, you have much deeper issues that need to be resolved with your faculty / tutor/ mentor. Not a website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Wolfy, here is a detailed proof, following Folland's hints.

> Problem 3.3.14 - If $\nu$ is an arbitrary signed measure and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X,M)$ such that $\nu\ll \mu$, there exists an extended $\mu$-integrable function $f:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ such that $d\nu = fd\mu$. Hints:
>
> a.) It suffices to assume that $\mu$ is finite and $\nu$ is positive.
>
> b.) With these assumptions, there exists an $E\in M$ that is $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$ such that $\mu(E)\geq \mu(F)$ for all sets $F$ that are $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$.
>
> c.) The Radon-Nikodym theorem applies on $E$. If $F\cap E = \emptyset$, then either $\nu(F) = \mu(F) = 0$ or $\mu(F) > 0$ and $|\nu(F)| = \infty$.

**Proof** - Let us work on hint a.).

Since $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X,M)$, there is a countable family $\{X_n\}_n$ of disjoint measurable subsets of $X$ such that, fo all $n$, $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ and $X=\bigcup_n X_n$.

Now, let $P$ and $N$ be a Hahn decomposition of $X$ for $\nu$. Then $X=P\cup N$, $P\cap N= \emptyset$ and, for all measurable set $A$,
$$\nu^+(A)=\nu(A\cap P) \quad \nu^-(A)=-\nu(A\cap N)$$

For each $n$,  $\nu^+|_{X_n}\ll \mu|_{X_n}$ and $\nu^-|_{X_n} \ll \mu|_{X_n}$.
If we can prove for those cases, that there are extended $\mu$-integrable functions $f_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $d\nu^+|_{X_n} = f_nd\mu|_{X_n}$ and extended $\mu$-integrable functions $g_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $d\nu^-|_{X_n} = g_nd\mu|_{X_n}$.

It is easy to see that $g_n = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $P\cap X_n$ and $f_n = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $N\cap X_n$. So, $h_n=f_n-g_n$ is well defined $\mu$-a.e.. (I means we will not have $\infty -\infty$).

Since $\{X_n\}_n$ is a countable family  of disjoint measurable subsets of $X$, we have that
$h= \sum_n h_n$ is a measurable function and $h:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ and we also have, for any $A$ measurable set,
\begin{align*} 
\nu(A) &= \sum_n\nu(A\cap X_n\cap P) + \sum_n\nu(A\cap X_n\cap N)= \\
&= \sum_n\nu^+(A\cap X_n) - \sum_n\nu^-(A\cap X_n)= \\
&= \sum_n \int_{A\cap X_n} f_n d\mu - \sum_n \int_{A\cap X_n} g_n d\mu= \\
&=  \int_{A} \sum_n f_n d\mu - \int_{A} \sum_n  g_n d\mu= \\
&=  \int_{A} \sum_n (f_n - g_n) d\mu = \\
& =\int_{A}  \sum_n  h_n d\mu =  \int_{A}  h d\mu
\end{align*}
So we have proved that, for any $A$ measurable set,
$$\nu(A) = \int_{A}  h d\mu$$
Since $\nu$ is a signed measure, it does not attain either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. It follows then that $h$ is not only measurable but it an extended $\mu$-integrable function. (In other word, either $\int h^+ d\mu <\infty$ or  $\int h^- d\mu <\infty$ or both).

Now, to complete the proof, all we need is to prove that

> If $\nu$ is a (positive) measure and $\mu$ is a finite measure on $(X,M)$ such that $\nu\ll \mu$, there exists an extended measurable function $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $d\nu = fd\mu$.

Consider the set
$$S = \{\mu(F) : \textrm{ $F$ is a $\sigma$-finite set for $\nu$ } \}$$

Since we have that $\mu$ is finite then clearly $S$ must be bounded which implies it has a finite supremum. We will define the supremum as
$$L = \sup\{\mu(F) : F \ \text{is a} \  \sigma\text{-finite set for} \ \nu\}$$
Now lets take a sequence $\{E_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ that are $\sigma$-finite with respect to $\nu$ and $\mu(E_n)\rightarrow L$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Now let $$E = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_n$$ then $\mu(E) \leq L$ since $E$ is a $\sigma$-finite set (being  a countable union of $\sigma$-finite sets). On the other hand, $\mu(E)\geq \mu(E_n)$ for all $n$ and since $\mu(E_n)\rightarrow L$ then $\mu(E) = L$. Now since $\mu(E) = L$ then clearly by definition of $L$ we have that $\mu(E) > \mu(F)$ for all sets $F$ that are $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$.
So we used hint b.). Now let us work on hint c.).

Now, since $\nu|_E$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\nu|_E\ll \mu|_E$ we apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem, and so there is $f_1:E\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ such that
$$\nu(A\cap E) =\int_{A\cap E} f_1 d\mu  \tag{1}$$

Now, given any measurable set $F$ such that  $F\cap E = \emptyset$, suppose that $\mu(F)>0$ and $\nu(F) <\infty$.  Then $E\cup F$ is $\sigma$-finite for $\nu$, (that is $E\cup F \in S$) and
$$\mu(E\cup F) =\mu(E) +\mu( F) > \mu(E)=L = \sup S$$
Contradiction.

So, for any measurable set $F$ such that  $F\cap E = \emptyset$,
we have two cases:

1. $\mu(F) =0$ then, since $\nu \ll \mu$, $\nu(F)=0$.
2. if $\mu(F)>0$ then $\nu(F)=+\infty$.

So, for any measurable set $F$ such that  $F\cap E = \emptyset$,

$$ \nu(F) = \int_F +\infty \chi_{E^c} d\mu $$

That means, for any measurable set $A$,

$$ \nu(A\cap E^c) = \int_{A\cap E^c} +\infty \chi_{E^c} d\mu \tag{2}$$

Let $f:X \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be defined as $f(x)=f_1(x)$ for $x \in E$ and $f(x)=+\infty$ for $x \notin E$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have, for any measurable set $A$,
$$\nu(A)= \nu(A\cap E)+ \nu(A\cap E^c)= \int_{A\cap E} f_1 d\mu +\int_{A\cap E^c} +\infty \chi_{E^c} d\mu= \int_A f d\mu$$

Comment: Hey Ramiro, I am just curious about your intuition with considering the set $S$. I follow everything up until that point, then I get a bit lost.

Comment: In the expression for $\nu(A)$ in part (a), how are you able to take $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ inside the integral. One can arbitrarily change summations and integrals when the $f_{n}$'s are non-negative. But in this case, $f_{n}$ is real valued. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, don't we need $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{A} |f_{n}| d\mu < \infty$?

Comment: @user82261 In part (a),  we assume to have extended $\mu$-integrable functions $f_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $d\nu^+|_{X_n} = f_nd\mu|_{X_n}$ and extended $\mu$-integrable functions $g_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $d\nu^-|_{X_n} = g_nd\mu|_{X_n}$. So $f_n$ and $g_n$ are non-negative functions.

Comment: @Ramiro Right but $h_{n}$ is a real valued extended $\mu-$ integrable function, right? You have used it in the expression where you changed the order of the sum and the integral? Or is that correct way to think about it is to first decompose $h_{n}$ into $f_{n} - g_{n}$, apply the result to each of these, and then combine them back again?

Comment: @user82261 We first decompose $h_n$. I have edited the steps to make it clearer.  Let me know if you have any further question.